# How to format python logs in log file using logging.FileHandler as one of handlers in config dictionary?

Tags: python, logging, formatting, python-logging

I have two files:

1. log.config.py
   This file contains all default configurations for logging and a method for 3 customization:

- whether to print logs in log file or not.
- whether to print logs in console or not.
- To decide the log levels.

```
import logging
import logging.config
from logging.config import dictConfig

LOGGING_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "default": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] - %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console_handler": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "default",},
        "file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "formatter": "default",
            "filename": "log.text"
            "mode": "w",
        },
    },
    "root": {"level": "INFO"},
    "loggers": {
        "": {"handlers": ["console_handler", "file_handler"], "propagate": True,}
    },
}


def configure_logger(log_file=False, console=True, log_level="DEBUG"):

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    dictConfig(LOGGING_DEFAULT_CONFIG)

    if not log_file:
        logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler())
    else:
        pass

    if not console:
        pass
    else:
        logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

    if not log_level:
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    else:
        logger.setLevel(getattr(logging, log_level))

    return logger
```

2. test.py
   From this script I am calling the function to give inputs for above three mentioned customization

```
from logging.config import dictConfig, fileConfig
from logging_tree import printout

from log_config import configure_logger


log = configure_logger()


def dummy_function():
    """Dummy Function to test logging inside a function"""
    log.debug("A debug message")
    log.info("An info message")
    log.warning("Something is not right.")
    log.error("A Major error has happened.")
    log.critical("Fatal error. Cannot continue")


dummy_function()

printout()
```

For Console logs "logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())" is taking formatting from LOGGING_DEFAULT_CONFIG, but for logs formatting in file "logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler())" is not taking any formatting from LOGGING_DEFAULT_CONFIG.

I have already tried:

- logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('log.text'))
- removing "filename" from "file_handler"
  but nothing worked out.

Q1. Is there any way to use the formatting from LOGGING_DEFAULT_CONFIG to write logs in the log file?

Q2. What is the best way to write a centralized config file and make changes to the requirement in all other python scripts?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I want to configure the log file from the "LOGGING_DEFAULT_CONFIG". How to reflect the "file_handler" configuration in below code snippet:                                                         
    if not log_file:
        logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler())
    else:
        pass